# Android service with START_STICKY crashes on killing app

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-lifecycle

This is my `Service` getting called on button click from an `Activity`. If I swipe my `Activity` left while `Service` is running it crashes. I have also tried running it in separate process by putting in `android:process=":remote"` in the manifest but it is still the same.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("Service", "Creating");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    Log.d("Started", "Service");

    type = intent.getIntExtra("Type",-1);
    mode = intent.getIntExtra("Mode",-1);
    rank = intent.getIntExtra("Rank", -1);
    latitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("Lat", -1.0);
    longitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("Long", -1.0);
    startTime = intent.getLongExtra("Start", 0);
    endTime = intent.getLongExtra("End", 0);
```

The error I am getting is:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.routofy.routofytest.MyLocationService@374afe93 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at com.routofy.routofytest.MyLocationService.onStartCommand(MyLocationService.java:89)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2896)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:148)
at    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

That is `null` pointer on `type = intent.getIntExtra("Type",-1);`

I understand that killing the app is killing the process and `Intent` this `Service` is getting is coming out to be `null`. But how to handle such cases that even if `Activity` is killed `Intent` is handed over to `Service`?
I want service to be totally independent of `Activity`. Also I am running it like:

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyLocationService.class);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand that killing the app is killing the process and intent this service is getting is coming out to be null.

Since you haven't posted the return value of `onStartCommand()` I believe that it's `START_STICKY` meaning that the service is recreated by the system with `null` `Intent` passed in.

> But how to handle such cases that even if activity is killed intent is handed over to service.

Just return [`START_REDELIVER_INTENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) flag, which means that:

*"If the system kills the service after `onStartCommand()` returns, recreate the service and call `onStartCommand()` with the last intent that was delivered to the service."*

Comment: Thanks. It works. Also any clue what will happen if i reboot the phone while service is running if i use START_REDELIVER_INTENT?

Comment: @newtoandroid Nothing, untill you start the app that in its turn starts the service. If you'd like to start the service on device boot, take a look at [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android?rq=1)